# Книги по Flash

Tags: flash, книги

Помогите, дорогие ХэшКод'овцы.

Есть великолепная идея хорошего приложения, но идеи мало для реализации. Хотелось бы научиться создавать приложения, но нормальных книжек не нашел, а возможно плохо искал.

Прошу Вас помочь мне с литературой по этому поводу, а ниже я опишу чему же я хочу научиться.

- Руководство по AS3 (основы я знаю, создавать простенькие Flash приложения с небольшим функционал умею, но хочется именно уметь создавать большие приложения, а вот именно с этим у меня проблемы)
- Изометрические движки (посоветуйте какие-нибудь проверенные движки, возможно те, с которыми Вы работали)

А вообще все книги, по которым можно научиться создавать приложения по типу Клондайк'а ВКонтакте. Интересует больше не как создавать такие приложения, а как делать такую механику, движения, анимацию и прочее.

Буду премного благодарен всем, кто поможет.

Comment: А что значит "основы я знаю, создавать простенькие Flash приложения с небольшим функционал умею" ? Вы понимаете, что такое классы, ооп? Или Вы по урокам научились в кадрах фигнюшки всякие делать?

Comment: Я понимаю что это, но вот с использованием этого в реальном проекте у меня небольшие проблемы. Классы использовать умею, а вот что уже касается абстрактных классов и далее совсем тьма.

Comment: Чтобы совет стал более точным, нужно понимать Ваш уровень. 
У Вас есть сложности с созданием классов, понимания работы событий  
и обменом данных между классами, модификаторами доступа и заной видимости 
в классах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/234334#291713